# Using Beamer to create a presentation, how can I have multiple superscript citations?

Tags: beamer, biblatex, citing, multiple-citations

Here is how I have set up my citations in the preamble:

```
%----------------Bibliography specifics-----------------%

\usepackage[natbib=true,
            style=ieee,
            sortcites=true,
            autocite=superscript,
            backend=biber]{biblatex} % ,useprefix=true
```

I have one slide that has three references and I'm getting a very strange error (visually) when I call the reference.

```
\begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{Aim 1 - Measuring Vitreoretinal Adhesion}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \heading{Quantifying Retinal Adhesion} \\[1ex]
            \begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
                \item[] Peel tests
                \begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
                    \item Direct peel of retina from choroid in monkey, cat,
                        and rabbit eyes
                        \autocite{Zauberman_1969, deguillebon_1971, Endo_1988}
                    \item Limitations
                    \begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
                        \item[-] Spherical geometry is altered in during removal
                        \item[-] Drying of the tissue with a vacuum
                    \end{itemize}
                \end{itemize}
                \item[] Bleb
                \begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
                    \item Subretinal injection of saline \autocite{Kita_1990}
                    \item Limitations
                    \begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
                        \item[-] Back-calculates the adhesion properties (Law
                            of Laplace)
                        \[P_s - P_v = \frac{2T}{R}\]
                        \item[-] Geometry issue
                    \end{itemize}
                \end{itemize}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{figure}
                \includegraphics[height=3cm]
                {./media/DeGuillebon_peel_1971}
                \caption{Close up view of peel test \autocite{deguillebon_1971}}
            \end{figure}\\[-3ex]
            
            \begin{figure}
                \includegraphics[height=3cm]
                {./media/kita_bleb_1990}
                \caption{Close up view of bleb test \autocite{Kita_1990}}
            \end{figure}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\note{\begin{itemize}
        \item Existing methods of retinal adhesion is between the outermost
            layer of the retina {\bf (choroid)}
        \item Bleb – Not every Bleb was spherical 
\end{itemize}}
```

Here is what the slide looks like:

[image]

When I comment out the part `autocite=superscript` it references properly [7]-[9].

I would love to use superscripts because they are much smaller in the slides rather than full text height citations.

Comment: Hint : This post explains how to provide an MWE that involves bibliographies, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography. Your current code is unnecessary specific.

Comment: Very attractive beamer theme.  Is the theme available in open?

Comment: Thank you!  I modified the Metropolis theme to have specific colors that differ from the default as well as adding a background image and new heading line.  I started with ```\usetheme[block=fill,progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}``` and went from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `\supercite` was missing two brackets. This appears to be a small bug in `biblatex-ieee`. (Reported at https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/pull/62. Fix already merged.)

Until a fixed version of `biblatex-ieee` is released, you can use the following redefinition

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[natbib=true,
            style=ieee,
            sortcites=true,
            autocite=superscript,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \bibopenbracket
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \let\multicitesubentrydelim=\supercitesubentrydelim
   \let\multiciterangedelim=\superciterangedelim
   \let\multicitesubentryrangedelim=\supercitesubentryrangedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \bibclosebracket}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer}

ipsum \autocites{sigfridsson,worman,geer}{nussbaum}

dolor \parencite{sigfridsson,worman,geer}
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [1]–[3]//ipsum [1]–[3],[4]//dolor [1]–[3]]

Comment: That worked perfectly!  Thank you.  I didn't know that IEEE didn't have superscript capability.  I just wanted to try and minimize the citation in a presentation to not attract attention to the citation.